# jQuery window width sometimes return wrong value

Tags: jquery, window, width

SOMETIMES when I call:

```
$(window).width();
```

the value returned is wrong (on all browsers except IE, on IE it is always correct). I use the line:

```
$('div.container p').text($(window).width());
```

to change the text of the `p` element so I could see what value was returned when I am resizing the window. Here is an example when the value returned is wrong: 
[image: http://prntscr.com/7biu4y]

In the top right corner, you can see what the actual dimensions are on Chrome.

I noticed that WHEN the value is wrong, it is always off by 17px.

NOTE that the value returned is NOT always wrong so most of the times the window looks as it should.

Help!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

@Inacio Schweller is correct.

To get a consistent cross-browser result, you can use the non-jQuery version:

`window.innerWidth`

Try typing this into the console of your browser and you'll see that it returns a consistent result regardless of the browser you are using.

Note: The non-jQuery version `window.outerWidth` returns the same result in IE and Chrome, but returns a slightly smaller value in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks to Inacio Schweller and to you Trevor. Using plain javaScript window.innerWidth returns value I need.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the scrollbar of the browser's viewport.
If you minimize the window enought to show the scrollbar, the viewport will say it's 17px smaller than your value. If the window is full, the 17px difference will not appear.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. How then I should deal with this and why browsers (except IE) even consider scroll bars when I don't have any content on the website just plain containers?